# Angular: ¿Cómo puedo convertir lng y lat a texto?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps, http

Tengo almacenada la lat y long y quiero convertirla a el nombre de la dirección (texto), estoy usando Angular Cli en su versión 12.1.4

Ayuda, porfavor

// De las siguientes variable obtengo la lat y la long
// this savedMarked = this.bookingService.bookingModel.latlng <--- latlng es quien trae el objeto //de la lat y lng

```
LocToText() {
    //this.savedMarker?
    const lat = this.savedMarker?.lat
    const long = this.savedMarker?.lng
    this.bookingService.formatedAdrress(lat, long).subscribe( res => {
      
      res
      
    }
  )
```

//La peticion a la api de google

```
 formatedAdrress(lat: any, long: any){
    // const lat = '';
    // const long = ''
    const Key = 'x';
    let api_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
    return this.http.get(api_URL + lat + long + '&key=' + Key)
  }
```

Este es el objeto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que recibo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en lo que envio en el body:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una forma: le agregas comillas simples.

Comment: ¿En donde deberia agregarselo?

Comment: `"'"+ lat + "'" +` Algo así.  Por otro lado, ¿qué error te da?

Comment: Ahhh, tu me dices en el servicio donde hago la petición? O en el suscribe?

Comment: De error me da 400

Comment: @fredyfx actualize la pregunta para que vea el error y tal vez usted me dice que puede ser más o menos

Comment: Creo que te falta una coma `get(api_URL + lat +','+ long + '&key=' + Key)`

Comment: Parece que sí, en la documentación mencionan: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: Sí, toda la razón, eso era, que no estaba enviando correctamente los parametros, muchas gracias

Comment: Es que obviamente los parámetros deben ir separdos de alguna manera para que google pueda parsearlos! De todas maneras, más *arreglado* que concatenando te quedaría usando un string template: `\`${api_RUL}${lat},${long}&key=${key}\`` OJO, son tildes al revés, no comillas simples.

Comment: Izlia, en todo caso, en la parte inferior de esta página, está un apartado donde dice `Tu Respuesta`, sería bueno que incluyas todo lo referente a cómo lo has solucionado, serás la luz de más personas que pasen por la misma situación y/o alguna similar :D también recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta luego de 24 horas, le ayudarás al sitio a mantener la buena salud por efecto de % de preguntas resueltas :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del objeto [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Por ejemplo:

```js
if (!this.savedMarker) return; // Según la implementación, this.savedMarker puede estar indefinido
const { lat, lng } = this.savedMarker;
this.bookingService.formatedAdrress(String(lat), String(lng)).subscribe( res => {    
  // ...
}
```

De manera que podrías tipear la función implmentada como:

```js
formatedAdrress (latitude: string, longitude: string) {
  let api_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
  return this.http.get(
    api_URL +
    latitude +
    longitude +
    '&key=' +
    GOOGLE_MAPS_GEOCODE_KEY
  )
}
```

El formato de la [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding) es:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&amp;key=GOOGLE_MAPS_GEOCODE_KEY`

Por lo que recomiendo verificar el valor de cada string para que se definan e implementen de la forma:

```js
this.http.get(
  api_URL + // Siendo api_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
  latitude +
  ',' +
  longitude +
  '&key=' +
  GOOGLE_MAPS_GEOCODE_KEY
);
```

O de manera un poco más resumida:

```js
this.http.get(`${api_URL}${latitude},${longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_GEOCODE_KEY}`);
```

Si estructuras la consulta de otra manera, es esperable que te retorne un error [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).